# Sending data received in one Twisted Web Server and send to second factory

Tags: twisted

thanks for payd atentions, i really need your help.

I am trying to write a simple program using Twisted framework that receive one txt request  from a web server, procesed that info and send a responce but other conection TCP. My really problem is How send the messege from the web server to the TCP conetions.

Comment: Here's how to write the [server](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html) and here's how to write a [client](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html)

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/ and http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html